# I log in and then I am anonymous?

Tags: ajax, services

I've been trying to debug an app where I am utilising ajax and trying to post content via services. However, I can't. What am I missing?

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'http://7.webcinizim.com/services/user/token.json',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(token) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(token));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://7.webcinizim.com/services/user/login.json',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
              username: "tolga",
              password: "tolga123"
            },
            success: function(user) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
              $.ajax({
                url: 'http://7.webcinizim.com/services/node.json',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'node[type]=page&node[title]=Hede',
                success: function() {
                  console.log("Node created");
                },
                error: function(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              });
            });
        }
      });
  }
});
```

UPDATE: My query looks like this now and I am getting Invalid JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://7.webcinizim.com/services/user/token.json',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(token) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(token));
    localStorage.setItem("token", token.token)
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://7.webcinizim.com/services/user/login.json',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        username: "tolga",
        password: "tolga123"
      },
      success: function(user) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://7.webcinizim.com/services/node.json',
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
            "node[type]": "page",
            "node[title]": "Hede"
          },
          headers: {
            "X-CSRF-Token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          success: function() {
            console.log("Node created");
          },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Services after login request in response You should get a X-CSRF-Token. You have to use it in header of next requests to keep "being logged in".
It should be in header for second (and all possible future) requests like:

```
headers: {
    "X-CSRF-Token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, this requires that I add a line `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-CSRF-Token,Content-Type` to .htaccess.

Comment: Also, when I use it, dev console says I'm using OPTIONS and not POST, any ideas?

Comment: please see mu updated question.

Comment: What do You mean by that? What says You are ysing OPTIONS? Is it working? I didn't know about the Allow-Contol-Allow-Headers thing, thx :)

Comment: From a different source I learned that OPTIONS is for querying whether the endpoint will accept our headers and whatnot. Also, I updated my question.